# Sysstat Time Options and Command Differences

Tags: ubuntu, logs, monitoring, sar, sysstat

I would like to track total CPU and memory use on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. For that purpose, I am about to install the sysstat library. I read the manuals of and posts on `sar` and related functions, but am still confused about the syntax.

**What I would like to do**: Record total CPU and memory use every five seconds. Export the data once a day as CSV and delete the binary data.

**What confuses me**: 1. There are multiple settings specifying time intervals. `sar -u %system -r %memused 5` records CPU and memory use every five seconds. On top of that, the package generates "activity reports" every ten minutes as defined by `5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1` in `/etc/cron.d/sysstat`. I am confused about what happens every five seconds and what happens every ten minutes. Does the program first cache the data every five seconds and then writes it to a file every ten minutes? 2. Multiple functions write to disk. Which of them do I need? `sar -u %system -r %memused -o 5`, `sadc -u %system -r %memused 5 -`, or `sa1`? 3. Do I need to execute the code that generates a daily CSV file (`sadf -d /var/log/sysstat/sa$(date +%d -d yesterday) > /home/some_user/sar_data.csv`) as a chron job?

As a side note: if anyone knows of a solution that would be computationally more efficient than this sysstat approach, feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

1. `5-55/10` runs the command at 5,15,25,35,45, and 55 seconds.
2. `debian-sa1 1 1` is `debian-sa1 [ interval [ count ] ]` so it will collect for one second one time.

In your `sar` command you do not have a *count* so it will accumulate for 5 seconds until stopped.

While it will significantly increase log size and CPU usage, as        [cron(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) examines cron entries every minute, .

```
   The time and date fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```

As cron runs into serious problems if the job takes longer to run than the interval between launches, it is *unsafe* to just adjust the cron entry to:

`*/1 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 10 5`

Or:

`` */1 * * * * root for i in `seq 1 5` ; do debian-sa1 1 1 ; sleep 10 ; done ``

But doing so as a test may show just how much CPU time and disk space this option will be. But the second command will have slightly less impact as it is only collecting for 1 second out of 10.

But the log files will be in similar size for either of above.

as neither `systat` nor `cron` are designed for that frequency of collection do not expect high stability of the granularity in the above.

Comment: Thanks, that is already helpful. Would you mind elaborating on a few details? 1. Are you sure that 5-55/10 refers to the seconds? I thought it refers to minutes. 2. I still did not fully understand what the different time references at the beginning and the end of the cron job imply. If I used `0 0 * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1`, it would record system stats only once a day at midnight, right?

Comment: If I used `0 0 * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 5 43200`, it would run 43200 queries over 5 seconds at midnight rather than 1 query every 5 seconds over a day starting at midnight, right? How do I get it to start once a day and keep collecting data once every five seconds? And where would I specify the `-u %system -r %memused` options in that `sa1` line?